# OpenVPN problem

Tags: centos, openvpn

I've Configure an OpenVPN (2.0.9) on a CentOS 6.2 (2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64) to accept OpenVPN client connection.
But when I try  to connect from Windows 7 by OpenVPN client tool it return me some error:

[Server side OpenVPN Config](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5711626/)

[Client Side OpenVPN Config](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5711631/)

[Client Side OpenVPN Log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5711635/)

Windows firewall is off
iptables (server) is off

any idea?

Comment: No logs on the server? You may increase the log file verbosity on the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your server config, "listen localhost" is wrong. That would listen on 127.0.0.1 (or similar), meaning it would not accept connections from outside the box. Your comment next to it doesn't make sense either; and also, you'd normally listen on a public IP.

Assuming the above is anonimizing (which you forgot to do in the client config):

- The `;` comments are OK (thanks to [TNW](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/37072/tnw) for pointing this out).
- Its somewhat weird that your server config does not give the path to the CA, key, and certificate. Possibly its not finding them?
- you have a host firewall on your server (or somewhere inbetween) that's blocking the packet to UDP/1194.
- you didn't actually start the server (possibly due to some error in the config—maybe one of the above—preventing it from starting, but you didn't provide a server log).

Further, glancing quickly at the config:

- you `push "dhcp-option DNS 4.2.2.1 "` ... You probably shouldn't do that. You'd typically only push a DNS server if you were pushing a private one, to be accessed over the VPN (so clients could use internal hostnames). And if you want a generic public DNS server, Google actually offers a few—4.2.2.1 isn't offered as such (at least not officially).
- you ought to heed that warning about MITM attacks in your client log, and read http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#mitm like it says. It *may* not apply since you're probably using a private CA—at least, if you trust *everyone* the private CA has given a certificate to.

Comment: thank you for your advice :)
I made some changes (comment local directive at all)
but when try to connect from client it return me [this  error](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5712153/) :

Comment: OpenVPN supports `;` comments. That comes with default config files, and it's a good way to distinguish options from their descriptions visually.

Comment: @Sasantorabkheslat Up your `verb`ose level. And it'd be helpful to get the server log, too. Possibly with a higher verbosity.

Comment: @TNW Thank you, answer updated w/r/t the `;`-style comments